# Remove groups with less than three unique observations

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset my data frame to keep only groups that have 3 or more observations on DIFFERENT days. I want to get rid of groups that have less than 3 observations, or the observations they have are not from 3 different days.

Here is a sample data set:

```
Group   Day
1       1 
1       3
1       5
1       5
2       2
2       2  
2       4 
2       4
3       1
3       2
3       3
4       1
4       5
```

So for the above example, group 1 and group 3 will be kept and group 2 and 4 will be removed from the data frame.

I hope this makes sense, I imagine the solution will be quite simple but I can't work it out (I'm quite new to R and not very fast at coming up with solutions to things like this). I thought maybe the diff function could come in handy but didn't get much further.

Comment: Try `df[df$Group %in% as.numeric(names(which(tapply(df$Day,df$Group,function(x) length(unique(x))>=3)))),]`

Comment: @Jaap how is this `r-faq`? I cannot wrap my head around everything being r-faq. Certainly there are more general, much more visited questions out there not tagged with r-faq. Would you explain it? thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) you could do:

```
library(data.table)
DT[, if(uniqueN(Day) >= 3) .SD, by = Group]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Group Day
> 1:     1   1
> 2:     1   3
> 3:     1   5
> 4:     1   5
> 5:     3   1
> 6:     3   2
> 7:     3   3
> ```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Day) >= 3)
```

which gives the same result.

Answer (score 6):

One idea using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   filter(length(unique(Day)) >= 3)

#Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
#Groups: Group [2]

#  Group   Day
#  (int) (int)
#1     1     1
#2     1     3
#3     1     5
#4     1     5
#5     3     1
#6     3     2
#7     3     3
```

Comment: instead of `length(unique(Day))` you could you `n_distinct(day)`

Comment: Nice one! Thanks @Arun

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus, I didn't see that you updated with `dplyr` solution. I added the `unique(length))` approach anyways.

Comment: np, having several options is always good ;-) (btw: the `.,` in your filter statement is not needed, I've taken the liberty to remove that; hope you don't mind)

Comment: Thanks @ProcrastinatusMaximus :)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `base R`

```
i1 <-  rowSums(table(df1)!=0)>=3
subset(df1, Group %in% names(i1)[i1])
#    Group Day
#1      1   1
#2      1   3
#3      1   5
#4      1   5
#9      3   1
#10     3   2
#11     3   3
```

Or a one-liner `base R` would be

```
df1[with(df1, as.logical(ave(Day, Group, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) >=3))),]
```