# Remove all rows of a category if zero in a % of cases

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, delete-row

I have the following data set of weekly retail data ordered after `Category`(e.g. Chocolate), `Brand` (e.g. Cadbury's), and `Week`(1-208). `CBX` is a unique global identifier for each brand.

```
Category Brand  Week   Sales    Price  CBX     
33       2      1      167650.  2.20   33 - 2          
33       2      2      168044.  2.18   33 - 2           
33       2      3      160770   2.24   33 - 2
```

I now want to remove the brands that have zero sales in more than 75% of the weeks (thus have positive sales in at least 156 weeks). 
At first I deleted all brands with any zero sales using `dplyr`, but it deleted too much of the data. This was the code I used:

```
library(dplyr)
Final_df_ <- Final_df %>%
  group_by(Final_df$CBX) %>%
  filter(!any(Sales==0 & Price==0))
```

Now I'm trying to change the code so it only deletes all rows belonging to a brand (`CBX`) if the sales of that brand are zero in more than 25% of the cases.
This is how far I've come:

```
Final_df_ <- Final_df %>%
  group_by(Final_df$CBX) %>%
  filter(!((Final_df$Sales==0)>0.75))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: `Final_df %>% group_by(Final_df$CBX) %>% filter(sum(Sales==0)/n() > 0.75)` (based on my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37835754/2204410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811383/2204410))

Comment: I tried `dput(df)` but it was such a long outpot, thank you showing me the trick with `head(df,20))`, Rui.

Thank you Jaap. I tried it and it works!